# Populate rails app with data from dump sql file

Tags: sql, database

I want to import database to rails app, 
I have a dump file of my database in which I have:

```
*!40000 ALTER TABLE `client` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `client` (`Id`,`ClientTypeId`,`Name`,`Address`,`Mobile`,`Phone`,`Fax`,`Email`,`ContactName`,`ContactMobile`,`ContactEmail`) VALUES 
 (69,1,'ФК Астана','БЦ Москва;-;-','72-99-50, 72-99-49','72-99-50, 72-99-49','72-99-50, 72-99-49','alima_fcast@mail.ru','Алима','610-291','alima_fcast@mail.ru'),
 (70,1,'Береке Каб','13 магистраль;-;-','965-094','965-094','965-094','d.nurmoldin@bkab.kz','Дидар','+77015145781','d.nurmoldin@bkab.kz'),
 (71,1,'Канам Агро','БЦ Астаналык ;3 этаж;3 этаж','500-000','500-000','-','a.tulubaeva@canam.kz','Асемгуль','',''),
```

The actual list is longer of course. Is there a way to place that INSERT statement somewhere in rails app and seed my database.

Assume I have Client model. 
In my development env i use sqlite, data is dumped from mysql database.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  ie MySQL, Postgres, SQLite etc?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, i am importing from MySql, and will use probably Postgres in production

Comment: To import sql into a mysql database do `mysql -u root db_name < sqlfile.sql`

Comment: I just went down this road with an application I ported from PHP/mySQL to Ruby on Rails/Postgres.  I strongly recommend exporting in CSV.  I can write up a detailed answer using this technique if you are interested.

Comment: and into postgres its `psql databasename < data_base_dump`

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with @steveklein: if you are exporting data from one dbms into another (eg mysql -> postgres) you can get caught out by odd differences between them, and maybe not realise until you are further down the road.  With a csv you know at least that it is just text: you know were you are with text strings, even if it's a bit more work to make sure they are imported/formatted properly.

Comment: @steveklein, yes i am.

Comment: I'll try to get to this today but time is tight.  Definitely Monday if not sooner.  Hope that works.

Comment: OK just posted it @yerassyl.  Hope it helps and don't hesitate to ask if you have questions or run into difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated my production database from `PHP`/`mySQL` to `Ruby on Rails`/`Postgres`. For background, I am running my `Rails` application on a Digital Ocean server using `NGINX`/`Unicorn`.

Essentially, I was looking for a nice database neutral approach where I wouldn't need to worry about database idiosyncrasies, but would be able to preserve all of my data.  I spent hours trying to migrate using YAML but it led to one problem after another, despite a lot of custom data massaging with `sed`, `perl`, etc.  After someone on SO suggested I give it a try, I moved to `CSV` and my life improved dramatically.

**Export from mySQL**

I was using `phpMyAdmin` to manage my `mySQL` database in my source system.  These are the steps I took to export my data:

1. Create a simple maintenance page and routed all site traffic to that page using rewrite rules in .htaccess.
2. Back up production database (I used this back up for all of my work).
3. Manipulate source data to match columns on target system (only needed if schema has changed).
4. Export to CSV one table at a time.  I used tab separators, double quotes as quotes and to quote special characters since they are used that way in `Postgres`, and replaced all NULLs with nothing.  I also removed all line feeds from data as I felt that would add complexity in the migration and removing them would not significantly impact my customer's data.
5. Copy data to destination server.  I actually did this in two steps - first to my Cloud9 IDE account using Cloud9's file upload and then from there to my server using `scp` (something like `scp -P 1234 table.txt user@10.20.30.40:/tmp`).

**Transform**

1. Add timestamp columns.  In my case, my tables did not all have them and they are expected in `Rails` (obviously a very good thing).  I actually did this transformation on my source system but I could have just as easily added two date fields to each record at this point in the process.  That is why I used tab separators - so that I could easily import the files as text into Excel and add these two columns.
2. `sed -i 's/\t/,/g' table.txt` - replace all tabs with commas.
3. `sed -i 's/\\//g' table.txt` - remove all backslashes (leftover from my days in `PHP` backslash hell).
4. `perl -i -pe 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g' table.txt` - remove non-ASCII characters.

**Load**

1. I had previously created all of the tables on my production server through a regular deploy and migration.
2. Run `truncate table;` in Postgres for each table to remove test data.
3. Run `\COPY table FROM '/tmp/table.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;` in Postgres for each table to load it into production.
4. Run `select count(id) from table;` in Postgres for each table and make sure the number matches the original number of rows.
5. Run `select setval('table_id_seq', (select max(id) FROM table));` in Postgres to reset Postgres auto-increment counter.

This last step was added as a result of a nasty little surprise learning.  When I migrated my tables, most of them had missing unique ids where legacy data had been removed.  When the data is migrated into `Postgres`, by default it will start auto incrementing at the lowest available id number.  This works fine until that block of available numbers is used up and your application fails to insert on a duplicate key error.

That is just about it.  I ran into other issues but there were generally not strictly data migration related.

I also tested most or all of this process about three times before doing the cutover and going live.  I strongly recommend testing as often as possible and also having friendly users take a look at the migrated data and use the system in pre-production.  Of course, mo data is mo problems, so YMMV depending on the size of your data set.

Hope this provides some help - let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article(linked below) to be helpful when I try to copy a database-dump(filename.sql in my case) file's data into the database that I use locally

basically, these are the steps outlined in the article:

1. `rails db:drop`
2. `rails db:create`
3. `rails db < mydatadump`

another approach mentioned in the article is using the postgres prompt. In the postgres command prompt you can perform the following actions:

1. `drop mydatabase`
2. `create mydatabase`
3. `psql -u username -p password mydatabase < mydatadump`

FYI - I only follow the first approach stated above, so, I'm not 100% sure of the second approach.

https://medium.com/ruby-rails-tips/importing-database-dump-in-ruby-on-rails-4591ff80e9e1